# Rails 3 initializes extremely slow on Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

I'm using RVM for managing environment, installed Ruby 1.9.2.p136  (i think its latest release.) and Rails 3, created gemsets and run bundler. everything working good so far 
but;

Rails initalizes extremely slow when running commands, i.e. generate, destroy, rake etc.
Takes about 30-45 seconds to complete command. This will never happens if use Ruby Enterprise Edition or Ruby 1.8.7

Why this happens. Any thoughts?
Running on Ubuntu 10.10, RVM, Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3

Thanks.

Comment: Is this on a brand new app, or on an existing app?

Comment: Checked in Sytem Monitor (Ubuntu). Tested now with rake db:migrate command its using %100 cpu with about 50mb ram

Comment: This is strace output 
http://shorttext.com/k6g37kpi52

Comment: seems like gettimeofday issue on linux. maybe your kernel has some extra configurations for timer?

Comment: No extra configurations. It is clean Ubuntu 10.10 installation. With RVM, Ruby 1.9.2 and gems.

Answer (score 7):

There is a thread about this on Rails-Core - http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-core/browse_thread/thread/88519ef5a53088a1/c01ba447c6dc0de7?lnk=raot

To quote Yehuda Katz

"There are things that the C require code does in 1.9 that slow things down.
One such example is re-checking $LOAD_PATH to make sure it is all expanded
on every require. This is something that should be addressed by ruby-core.
I'll open a ticket on redmine if there isn't one already."

I am also experiencing this problem and a $LOAD_PATH issue seems like a potential cause. Lets hope it gets fixed soon.

Comment: However it looks like the fix is a fairly major fix and this is scheduled for 1.9.3 so who knows when it will be fixed! [Require performance bug](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/3924)

Answer (score 3):

Try to strace (on unix), dtruss (on mac) your command (might need to "sudo" though). It'll show you where the process is spending its time. Notice where it pauses. This is definitely not normal.

Comment: I found process ID of the Ruby instance then checked using strace. Process log has lots of wait process. 

"[pid  2204] 04:26:08.156009 futex(0x58c1c4, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1015189, {0, 9842003}) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)"

Comment: So network IO, could it be that you are accessing the DB via IP? Do you have proper dns resolver? Try to switch all domain names to IP addresses. You could also run a "netstat -a" to see what/where it is trying to go to.

Comment: Currently Rails working on localhost (with development environment)

Comment: strace and dtruss are fantastic diagnostic tools that I just learned about thanks to this response.  Thanks Zepplock