# Delay when issuing any rails commands on windows vista

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, windows-vista, delay

Everytime I run any rails command on my windows vista dev box there is always something like a 30 second delay before the command does anything. I don't have the firewall enabled and the virus protection is disabled. Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789248/rails-3-initializes-extremely-slow-on-ruby-1-9-2

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on this specific issue, but I can say I had nothing but problems trying to run Rails on Windows in the past. That said, after trying Ubuntu and MacOs, I still prefer to use Windows as my primary UI. My solution is to run Ubuntu Server on a VM, and use a Samba file share to access dev files, with putty as my primary console interface. The linux command line is far more powerful, and is where the Rails ecosystem is really geared to be running.

VirtualBox: http://virtualbox.com

Ubuntu: http://ubuntu.com

Samba: http://www.samba.org/

Putty: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/

With these tools, you can run your Rails stack in a nice linux server environment, and still enjoy the utility and functionality of the Windows GUI. (Although I'd recommend you move from Vista to 7)